# Factor analysis categorical data: dummy vs polychoric matrix

Tags: r, categorical-data, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I want to run a factor analysis in `R` (using `lavaan`), however, *some* of my variables are categorical/nominal (e.g. Yes, Yes but..., No, No but...)

I'm wondering whether its more appropriate to:

1. Calculate the polychoric correlation matrix and use that as the input data to lavaan. Then interpret the results like normal or
2. Create dummy variables for each of the categorical items, then calculate a correlation matrix and proceed as normal without worrying about polychoric correlations?

Does it make a difference either way? Which approach is preferred?

Comment: Neither will do. Polychoric correlation is appropriate for ordinal data, but yours looks like nominal. Factor analysis _per se_ is not for nominal variables hence not for dummy variables. Correspondence analysis is the analogue of it intended for nominal data.

Comment: From what I've researched, correspondence analysis works with categorical nominal data only. Is there a technique that can work with both continuous and categorical (without having to discretize the continuous variables)?

Comment: Categorical PCA (CATPCA) - you might want to browse the site to read more of it - is such technique. It quantifies (turns into interval) categorical variables - ordinal or nominal and simultaneously it can process originally interval/continuous ones along. Implementations which I know need truly continuous ones be discretized at input, which is a bit awkward. However, since you are allowed to discretize to any number of bins (even up 100 or so), the variables remain almost continuous as they were.